# Why does this code leak? (simple codesnippet)

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, hdf5

Visual Studio shows me several leaks (a few hundred lines), in total more than a few MB. I traced it down to the following "helloWorld example".
The leak disappears if I comment out the H5::DataSet.getSpace() line.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include "cpp/H5Cpp.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
_CrtSetDbgFlag ( _CRTDBG_ALLOC_MEM_DF | _CRTDBG_LEAK_CHECK_DF ); // dump leaks at return

H5::H5File myfile;
try {
    myfile = H5::H5File("C:\\Users\\yyy\\myfile.h5", H5F_ACC_RDONLY);
}
catch (H5::Exception& e) {
    std::string msg( std::string( "Could not open HDF5 file.\n" ) + e.getCDetailMsg() );
    throw msg;
}

H5::Group myGroup = myfile.openGroup("/so/me/group");
H5::DataSet myDS = myGroup.openDataSet("./myfloatvec");
hsize_t dims[1];
//myDS.getSpace().getSimpleExtentDims(dims, NULL); // <-- here's the leak

H5::DataSpace dsp = myDS.getSpace(); // The H5::DataSpace seems to leak
dsp.getSimpleExtentDims(dims, NULL);
//dsp.close(); // <-- doesn't help either

std::cout << "Dims: " << dims[0] << std::endl; // <-- Works as expected

return 0;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. I've been on this for hours, I hate unclean code...

Comment: What is HS::H5File ? can you show the definition what is dsMean.getSpace.getSimpleExtentDims definition?

Comment: We need more code. What does `H5::DataSpace::getSpace()` really do ?

Comment: I'm sorry, I thought it's obvious but obviously it is not. Those are functions from the C++ interface of the HDF5 library. It's this one: http://www.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/doc/cpplus_RM/classH5_1_1DataSet.html

getSpace() returns a copy of the DataSpace, where I can get the dimensions of my data.

Comment: Maybe there is something like releaseSpace...

Answer (score 0):

Use [H5::DataSet::vlenReclaim](http://www.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/doc/cpplus_RM/classH5_1_1DataSet.html#4e76899f034982233893d98a994e1020) to reclaim the memory after you are done using it.

Comment: Hmm I have looked at this now and I must say that I do not really understand. The only thing remotely useful I could found was http://www.hdfgroup.org/ftp/HDF5/current/src/unpacked/c++/test/tvlstr.cpp but I have now idea what's going on and how to use it in my much simpler code.

Comment: I have still not been able to resolve this problem or understand the example. Any additional help would be very welcome from my side.

Answer (score 0):

The variable length reclaim is only applicable if you're using variable length datatypes, which I don't think you would be in this example. I think you just have to close the data space after you're done using it.